# engine for cross-platform layouts like these ones for mindmapping

Tags: android, layout, cross-platform, mindmapping

I want to create a program. Part of its gui is similar to mindmapping or yahoo-pipes (you got the idea). And I want to be able to port this program to Windows, Linux and Android (don't really care about Macs).

So can you help me to choose a cross-platform library for drawing and operating such GUI?

I haven't chosen the language yet. I prefer .NET, but there can be problems with cross-platforming (have anyone tried android-mono?). Sometime I do C/C++, so it's also an option; I'm learning Erlang now, so if there is something brilliant for Erlang, I'd like to hear about it.

I understand that Android is mainly Java platform, so I'm ready to implement everything for PCs in C# or whatever language and then, with that experience, write a port to Android in Java (or participate in androidmono :).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can target all those platforms with Java. There's no cross-platform drawing library that targets all those platforms however.